# Access Compass assets from JS

Tags: javascript, sass, compass

The question is really simple: how can i access my Compass assets within JS file?

Case: i write React app with some styles written in SCSS with Compass, building it all with Grunt. I have some static assets which i want to use inside `<img>` tag in React components and i want to somehow resolve my assets using Compass. In stylesheets we have `image-url` function and i want something like this in my JS files.

Is there any solutions to achieve such functionality?

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass or Compass?  You can't compile or otherwise process JavaScript from Sass or Compass because they **only work on Sass (SCSS/SASS)** files.

Comment: yeah, i know. i just thought that there should be some kind of binding from compass to javascript to get easily access assets urls.

Comment: I understood the question to be assuming the javascript files were installed as part of a gem, e.g. bootstrap and he wants to access them but without the rails pipeline that usually provides that service.